# Add content to a panel using the admin dashboard template

Tags: javascript, extjs

The application we're building is built upon the [admin dashboard template](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard) provided by Sencha. When loading specific pages, we want to be able to dynamically change the content before the page is rendered. **What would be the best way to accomplish this?**

So far we've added a controller which allows us to run functions on page load, but we've been unable to find a way to use this to manipulate components of a page.

Example of a page:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.home.Page', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'page',

    requires: [
        'Ext.container.Container',
        'Ext.grid.Panel',
        'Ext.window.*',
        'Ext.ux.GMapPanel'
    ],

    controller: 'pagecontroller',

    anchor: '100% -1',
    layout: 'fit',
    items : [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            id: 'pagepanel',
            title: 'test'
        }
    ]
});
```

Example of the controller:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.home.PageController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.pagecontroller',

    init: function () {                                 //Run function on panelload();
    }
});

function panelload(){
var panelX = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    autoShow: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    title: 'test',
    closeAction: 'hide',
    width: 450,
    height: 450,
    html: '<p>foobar</p>'
};
    Ext.getCmp('pagepanel').add(panelX);
}
```

My current code does not spawn any errors nor does it do anything.

Comment: can you share some of what you have already accomplished? any errors?

Comment: Please provide the code you tried, see the guidelines how to ask good questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the `panelload` function called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1pr5). I moved the `panelload` function into the viewcontroller and call it in the init function.
The panel is added as expected into the test panel

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.home.PageController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.pagecontroller',

    init: function () {
        this.panelload(); // executes the function after view is ready
    },

    panelload: function () {
        var panelX = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            autoShow: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'test',
            closeAction: 'hide',
            width: 450,
            height: 450,
            html: '<p>foobar</p>'
        });
        Ext.getCmp('pagepanel').add(panelX);
    }
});
```

Following the complete code.

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.home.PageController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.pagecontroller',

    init: function () {
        this.panelload();
    },

    panelload: function () {
        var panelX = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            autoShow: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'test',
            closeAction: 'hide',
            width: 450,
            height: 450,
            html: '<p>foobar</p>'
        });
        Ext.getCmp('pagepanel').add(panelX);
    }
});

Ext.create({
    xclass: 'Ext.container.Container',
    controller: 'pagecontroller',

    anchor: '100% -1',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        id: 'pagepanel',
        title: 'test'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```